# ReflextionException, Class does not exist (Laravel command)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.3. I have wrote 2 laravel commands but when I call they from the window's cmd, just one works fine(command:name), the other(command:delayedPayment) gives me the next error:

[image]

But when I comment the DelayedPayment call, it works fine.

app/Console/Kernel.php

```
<?php
   namespace App\Console;

   use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
   class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
   {
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\GenerateInvoice',
        'App\Console\Commands\DelayedPayment',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('command:name')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('command:delayedPayment')->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

app/Console/Commands/DelayedPayment.php

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
namespace App\Http\Business;
namespace App\Http\Entities;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class DelayedPayment extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'command:delayedPayment';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        ...

    }
}
```

Its necessary to do something else?.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As according to your code, you've mentioned 3 namespaces inside `DelayedPayment.php` file, you should mention only one namespace per file at the top:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands; // <-------- Use only one namespace per file

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class DelayedPayment extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'command:delayedPayment';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        ...

    }
}
```

Read more about [PHP Namespacing Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see **ReflextionException** in Laravel, check your namespaces at first.